# In javascript how do you detect if the user held a key or not?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a game which has the feature that if you hold the shift key, the player will speed up. I tried to use keyEvent but it can't detect the key is held or pressed. and when I release the shift key, the player remains in speed up mode and won't change the speed back to normal. is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: When a key is pressed, a `keydown` event is fired, then when it is released a `keyup`event is fired.  Can't help you with an answer - since you need to show what you have already tried.  You might be using the `keypress` event - which is not going to be as helpful to do what you want.  Suggestion: Use `keydown` / `keyup` handlers and if you still run into issues post a real question (i.e  With code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen for two events: `keydown` and `keyup`. In every event type you should check for key (the keycode of "shift" is 16), and on `keydown` you should start an action, and on `keyup` stop it (if `event.keyCode === 16`). Here is a simple example with text color, it becomes red while "shift" is pressed (don't forget to click on opened window of the snippet, it will not work without it because without focusing on this window all events will be "out of scope" for the snippet):

```js
var onkeydown = (function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) {
    document.getElementById("target").style.color = "red";
  }
});

var onkeyup = (function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 16) {
    document.getElementById("target").style.color = "black";
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="target">Red when holds "shift"</h1>
```

Comment: Worth noting that there are issues if the element isn't in focus when the key is pressed or released (i.e. doesn't get the event), e.g. click in the snippet, hold shift (text turns red), click outside the snippet, release shift. Text remains red. Focus back on snippet, text still red.

Comment: @RobG I'm not a web-browser game developer, I gave simple solution to show that it's possible. And isn't it a normal behavior? When you switch between inputs on webpage using "tab" and then click on another window on your PC, "tab" will not work for that page anymore while this tab still be out of focus. Isn't it?

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that events have a context, so the OP needs to be mindful of that. ;-)